# How can I find my web element using the correct relative xpath

Tags: selenium, dom, xpath, relative-path

I am having trouble identifying a specific web element from the DOM. It is a button element, and there are 4 of them in the DOM, exact the same. The one that I need is the third one from the top.

So far I have written the following Xpath:

```
//button[@class='btn btn-success add-instrument']
```

This gives me 4 options. I have also tried:

```
//button[contains(text(), 'texthere')]
```

This also gives me 4 options. I have tried traversing from above and below, but that does not work either.

I want to: Index the third element, but can't get it to work.

What I have tried (with both options, mentioned above)

```
//button[contains(text(), 'texthere')]//[3]
```

I have also tried other indexes, but it finds nothing.

SOLVED BY USING:
"(//button[@class='btn btn-success add-instrument'])[3]"

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML including the parent nodes

Comment: My bad, forgot that indeed. It is already solved, next time I will post it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below xpath.It will identify the 3rd button.

```
"(//button[contains(text(), 'texthere')])[3]"
```

or

```
"(//button[@class='btn btn-success add-instrument'])[3]"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Putting in between ( ), made me select the index. Why does this make such a difference?

Comment: because () giving you the absolute Xpath of element.Can you please accept my answer by clicking accept of my code message if it helps you.